# How to make overflow scroll appear horizontally but make the overflow of the tooltip be visible vertically and horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make it so that the overflow scroll of this container(horizontally), appears while the vertical overflow is visible as well? On top of that, I would also want the absolutely positioned tooltip/popup to have its overflow to show horizontally.

Basically, I need to:

- show overflow scroll horizontally
- show overflow of the popup anywhere(right now it only appears below or above, but not on the left side or right side on top of its parent container)

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Xf3dc6YkLW

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

red line being the scrollbar, and the black box, being the tooltip, being able to appear on top of its parent div

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML code given below to get the desired result:

```
<div class="relative mx-auto mt-8 w-[700px] h-40 bg-red-100 overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-visible">
  <h1 class="text-center font-bold p-2">Store Items</h1>
  <div class="grid grid-flow-col items-center gap-x-3">
    <div class="relative w-96 h-24 bg-blue-700 group overflow-hidden">
      <div class="bg-green-200 w-full h-20 absolute top-0 left-0 hidden group-hover:block overflow-hidden">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="relative w-96 h-24 bg-blue-700 group overflow-hidden">
      <div class="bg-green-200 w-full h-20 absolute top-0 left-0 hidden group-hover:block overflow-hidden">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="relative w-96 h-24 bg-blue-700 group overflow-hidden">
      <div class="bg-green-200 w-full h-20 absolute top-0 left-0 hidden group-hover:block overflow-hidden">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not the desired result though, as we want the tooltip to appear at the bottom or outside of its parent container